# Multiple url redirection in apache :mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to Apache and wish to redirect an existing url (1) to new url(2) and then to final url(3). The redirection from url (1)  to url(2) is existing redirect rule defined and we cannot by pass it. Due to this we cannot jump form jump directly from url (1) to url(3). Below is the exsitng code:

for eg:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule ^/portal-web-payment/(.*)$ /portal-web/$1 [R]
      RewriteRule ^/portal-web/abc/portal/payment/web/mbbQuickRecharge/(.*)$ - [L]
 </IfModule>
```

I wish to insert below rule into this existing one, which is not working.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)(portal-web/abc/portal/payment/web/mbbQuickRecharge/PrepaidQuickRechargeController.jpf)(.*)$ http://yahoo.com/servlet/du/en/mobilebroadbandrecharge.html [L,R=302]
```

Below is the final Redirect url we wrote, which is not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule ^/portal-web-payment/(.*)$ /portal-web/$1 [R]
      RewriteRule ^/portal-web/abc/portal/payment/web/mbbQuickRecharge/(.*)$ - [L]
      RewriteRule ^/(.*)(portal-web/abc/portal/payment/web/mbbQuickRecharge/PrepaidQuickRechargeController.jpf)(.*)$ http://yahoo.com/servlet/du/en/mobilebroadbandrecharge.html [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

If suppose the rule is not working is due to already existence of apache flag [L], we cannot place our url before this due to project constraints.

Kindly suggest a way.

Thanks in advance.

Update 1:
Hi, its in .conf file.
the servername is our local env : in.test.it:90

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        ServerName in.test.it:90
        RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^/portal-web-payment/(.*)$ /portal-web/$1 [R]
      RewriteRule ^/portal-web/abc/portal/payment/web/mbbQuickRecharge/(.*)$ - [L]
      RewriteRule ^/(.*)(portal-web/abc/portal/payment/web/mbbQuickRecharge/PrepaidQuickRechargeController.jpf)(.*)$ http://yahoo.com/servlet/du/en/mobilebroadbandrecharge.html [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is this in .htaccess or in Apache config file? Also what URL are you using for testing?

Comment: Hi anubhava, i have updated the question with Update 1. please check

Comment: OK good, also tell what url are you using to test these rules and what is the error?